# Check that every if has a matching endif

Tags: java, algorithm, language-agnostic, bitcoin

I recently had to code up an interpreter for Bitcoin's script language; part of this involved coming up with an algorithm to check that the control flow in a given script made sense (i.e. every `OP_IF` had a matching `OP_ENDIF`, every `OP_ELSE` and `OP_ENDIF` had a matching `OP_IF`, etc.).

This is what I came up with:

```
public class if_else_checker {

public static boolean search(String[] commands, String[] tracker, int if_index) {
    boolean seenElse = false;
    for (int i = if_index; i < commands.length; i++) {
        if (commands[i].equals("OP_ELSE")) {
            if (seenElse == true && tracker[i] == null) return false;
            if (tracker[i] == null) {
                tracker[i] = "OP_ELSE";
                seenElse = true;
            }
        }

        else if (commands[i].equals("OP_ENDIF")) {
            if (tracker[i] != null && tracker[i].equals("OP_ENDIF")) 
            {
                continue;
            }
            tracker[i] = "OP_ENDIF";
            return true;
        }

        else if (commands[i].equals("OP_IF")) {
            if (tracker[i] != null && tracker[i].equals("OP_IF")) {
                continue;
            }
            tracker[i] = "OP_IF";
            if (search(commands, tracker, i + 1) == false) return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static boolean validate(String[] args) 
{
    String[] tracker = new String[args.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
    {
        if (args[i].equals("OP_IF")) 
        {
            if (tracker[i] == null || !tracker[i].equals("OP_IF")) 
            {
                tracker[i] = "OP_IF";
                if (search(args, tracker, i + 1) == false) return false;
            }

            else continue;
        }

        else if (args[i].equals("OP_ELSE"))
        {
            if (tracker[i] == null || !tracker[i].equals("OP_ELSE")) return false;
        }

        else if (args[i].equals("OP_ENDIF"))
        {
            if (tracker[i] == null || !tracker[i].equals("OP_ENDIF")) return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(validate(args));
}
```

}

It works, but I was wondering if there is a way to optimise it/if there is a standard way of doing this? (One optimisation is to have `validate()` return the index of the `OP_ENDIF` it finds, rather than a boolean; this would change runtime from quadratic-time to linear).

Answer (score 0):

The best way of solving this is by using a Stack data structure. Every new opening instruction (e.g. OP_IF) is pushed into the stack. When you find a closing instruction (e.g. OP_ENDIF), you pop the top element of the stack and check if it is the corresponding opening instruction for that closing instruction. If so, then it's valid, and you proceed to the next step. In the end, if the stack is empty then the control flow you're checking is correct. Otherwise, it's not.

Comment: I'm not sure that works here, because you also need to catch things like having multiple OP_ELSE statements for an OP_IF. Having a Stack works for making sure that every OP_IF has a matching OP_ENDIF, but not for the other stuff.

Comment: Then I'd suggest that you use a lexical analyzer (like flex (http://flex.sourceforge.net/) or ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/)) to create the rules to parse your code.

Comment: Oh, I mean, the code above works. I was just curious if there's a more standard way of doing it.

Comment: The check also fails if the stack is empty when an OP_ENDIF is found.